# Как добраться до элемента страницы?

Tags: html, css

Попал в руки шаблон, кое-что пришлось доделать, но вот столкнулся с патовой ситуацией. В самом низу страницы (footer) есть ссылка на политику безопасности, и при клике на нее должен появляться текст. Так вот проблема: добраться до этой ссылки никак не получается (какая-то чехарда со слоями). Пробовал и z-index, и вытаскивать слои и перетаскивать их, но все равно не получается. Помогите разобраться.
Ссылка на: [проект](http://smarty.16mb.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в теге `<video>`. А вообще то `z-index` спасает:

CSS

```
div#footer {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`<video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" id="background">` у вас всё заслоняет.

Если перенести этот блок в самый конец хотя бы `<div class="container">`, то будет хорошо